# Can't draw cubic with single color

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Here is how the cubic looks like:
[image]

I am using single color to specify every vertex before draw the cubic, but the cubic turns out not as i wished. I have enabled `depth_color_test` and also clear `COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` and `DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT` before drawing.

Here is the code:
https://github.com/ufo22940268/Android_RollingBall/blob/master/src/hongbosb/rollingball/model/GLEnvironmentEntity.java

Comment: "Turns out not as wished" how? What *should* it look like?

Comment: Every face with just one color. For example, the front face is red and   right face is blue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decimal separator here:

```
static public final float VERTEX_COLOR_ARRAY[] = {
    1.0f, 0,0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0,0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0,0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0,0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

    0.0f, 1,0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1,0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1,0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1,0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

    0.0f, 0,0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0,0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0,0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0,0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

    1.0f, 0,0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0,0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0,0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0,0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
};
```

should be a period (`.`), not a comma. Right now, they’re being treated as separate elements and throwing your indices out of whack.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have checked it a lot, but can't found this tiny mistake. I think i should found a better syntax highlight plugin.